# Click event not recognized on mobile browser Aframe-AR.js

Tags: mobile, click, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I am working on an Augmented reality scene using Aframe and AR.js. I am currently rendering obj models when the marker is detected. My requirement is to be able to click on individual models upon rendering and also static objects (buttons) . For some reason click event is not triggered properly on aframe entities when I test it on mobile devices , very rarely it detects the touch  but it works fine when I test it on a desktop using a webcam. This is my approach -

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('cursor-listener', {
init: function () {
this.el.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {

  console.log('I was clicked at: ', evt.detail.intersection.point);
 });
}
});
</script>
</head>  
<body>
<a-scene embedded arjs='trackingMethod: best; debugUIEnabled: false;'>      

   <a-marker id="marker" preset='hiro' cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">      
    <a-entity  material=" src: url(box.png) " class="collidable" cursor-listener position="0 -1 0"></a-entity>  
   </a-marker>

    <a-camera-static>
      //button a child of the camera.
     <a-entity id="red" material="color: red" class="collidable" geometry="primitive: box" cursor-listener position="0 0 -4" scale="0.3 0.3 0.3"></a-entity>  
    </a-camera-static>

  </a-scene>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I have tried this https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/416#issuecomment-425078800
solution, it make it better, just not accurate enough, the click is detected when clicked outside the object.
Is there anything any way to fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you might be looking for is dropping the idea of handling the click with a gaze-like cursor and go for a plain mouse/touch click like explained [here](https://medium.com/chialab-open-source/how-to-handle-click-events-on-ar-js-58fcacb77c4).